# получить конкретное свойство конкретного объекта в списке объектов

Tags: java

у меня есть ArrayList. в этом списке находится множество объектов определенного класса (одного и того же).
через цикл я хочу перебрать каждый элемент списка и проверить одно из свойств.
как мне это правильно сделать? мой способ не работает (не дает обратится через геттер)

```
for (int i = 0;i<list.size();i++){
            if(list.get(i).getName() == /*свойство по которому проверяю*/){
                /*пытаюсь обратится к свойству и получить значение через геттер прописанный в классе*/
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего ты не указал тип листа. Например

```
...
List list = getList();
...
```

Правильнее будет

```
List<MyClass> list = getList();
```

В таком случае, после получения элемента по индексу ты сможешь обращаться к нему, как к экземпляру класса `MyClass`.

Можно еще скастить полученный объект (что я бы не рекомендовал).

```
((MyClass)list.get(i)).getName()
```

Читается такое сложнее. И ошибок может возникнуть больше